# Vue js seems to be returning nested objects as strings?

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js

I have an object

```
   var user = {
      name:"test",
      number:"9666-0503",
      details:{
          test:"cannot_access_this",
          second_field:"nope_no_go"
      }
   }
```

Im calling an action in Vue JS

```
[TYPES.FETCH_USER]({ commit }) {
    api.get('user').then(({ data }) => {
        commit(TYPES.STORE_USER, data)
        console.log(data)
        // This returns perfectly fine and valid.  If I do 
        //console.log(data.details.test), I get the correect value
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
},
```

Then the mutation

```
[TYPES.STORE_USER](state, data) {
    state.user = data
    localStorage.set("user", state.user)
},
```

In my getters file

```
getUser: state => {
    return state.user
}
```

In my Component Im doing

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(["getUser"]),
},
mounted(){
   this.getData()
},
methods: {
  getData() {
    this.$store.dispatch(TYPES.FETCH_USER);
  }
```

}

And in the template

```
    <h1>{{getUser.name}}</h1><!-- this works -->
    <h2>{{getUser.number}}</h2><!-- this works -->
    <h3>{{getUser.details.test}}</h3> <!-- THIS FAILS!!-->
```

So getUser.details.test fails.  However...if I just do

```
    <h3>{{getUser.details}}</h3>
```

It then prints out what appears to be a string version of the details object??! Like what follows....

```
    <h3>{"test":"cannot_access_this","second_field":"nope_no_go"}</h3>
```

What is going on here!??

The wierdest thing is if I just console.log(state.user) at any time, it returns correctly.  And is a full object.  Why when Im accessing it in a template, is it stringifying any nested objects?

Comment: You're calling `this.$store.dispatch(TYPES.FETCH_USER);` which would call the `TYPES.FETCH_USER` action, not the mutation. Also, a mutation just has the `state` object as the first parameter. You have `{ state }`, which is a destructured object containing with a `state` property. So, if you are actually somehow calling the mutation, you're setting `state.state.user`, which isn't what you want

Comment: No sorry I used the wrong wording,  Im calling an action.  the action is TYPES.FETCH_USER.   Ive changed my code to reflect the answer below.  Still doesn work however.... :( It only seems to work for single level objects.  Any nesting returns stringed versions of these objects

Comment: So yeah, like acdcjunior said, initially, `getUser` is going to be set to whatever the value of `state.user` is initialized to in your vuex store. It seems most likely that the initial value of `state.user` is an empty object, so trying to access `state.user.details.test` results in an error. The simplest fix would be to initialize `state.user` with a `details` property: `state: { user: { details: {} } }`

Answer (score 1):

[**Mutations must be synchronous.**](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html#mutations-must-be-synchronous) Using async code in mutations yield all kinds of untraceable weird behaviors.

As the docs suggest, you should move the asychronous code to an **action**, like:

```js
mutations: {
    [TYPES.FETCH_USER](state, data) {
        state.user = data
    }
    //...
},
actions: {
    fetchUsersActionName({ commit }) {
        return api.get('user').then(({ data }) => {
            commit(TYPES.FETCH_USER, data)
            console.log(data)
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }
}
```

And use it with `.dispatch()`, not `.commit()`, like:

```js
this.$store.dispatch('fetchUsersActionName');
```

## The error

Check the below demos for reason why you get the error:

> ```
> <h1>{{getUser.name}}</h1><!-- this works -->
> <h2>{{getUser.number}}</h2><!-- this works -->
> <h3>{{getUser.details.test}}</h3> <!-- THIS FAILS!!-->
> ```

This first demo throws an error, because initially `getUser.details.test` is `undefined`, and as such it tries to access `undefined.test`, which throws an error:

```js
var globalUser = {
  name:"test",
  number:"9666-0503",
  details:{
    test:"cannot_access_this",
    second_field:"nope_no_go"
  }
};
var TYPES = {FETCH_USER: 'TYPESFETCHUSER'};
   
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {user: {}},
  mutations: {
    [TYPES.FETCH_USER](state, data) {
      state.user = data
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchUsersActionName({ commit }) {
      setTimeout(() => commit(TYPES.FETCH_USER, globalUser, 2000)); // simmulate asynchronous code
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getUser: state => state.user
  }
});
new Vue({
  store: store,
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapGetters(['getUser']),
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getData()
  },
  methods: {
    getData() { this.$store.dispatch('fetchUsersActionName'); }
  }
})
```

```css
span {font-family: monospace; font-weight: bold; color: red } h1,h2,h3 {font-size: medium; display: inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<span>This throws an error, because initially .details is undefined.</span>
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{getUser.name}}</h1> |
  <h2>{{getUser.number}}</h2> |
  <h3>{{getUser.details.test}}</h3>
</div>
```

Without `.test` there's no error:

```js
var globalUser = {
  name:"test",
  number:"9666-0503",
  details:{
    test:"cannot_access_this",
    second_field:"nope_no_go"
  }
};
var TYPES = {FETCH_USER: 'TYPESFETCHUSER'};
   
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {user: {}},
  mutations: {
    [TYPES.FETCH_USER](state, data) {
      state.user = data
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchUsersActionName({ commit }) {
      setTimeout(() => commit(TYPES.FETCH_USER, globalUser, 2000)); // simmulate asynchronous code
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getUser: state => state.user
  }
});
new Vue({
  store: store,
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapGetters(['getUser']),
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getData()
  },
  methods: {
    getData() { this.$store.dispatch('fetchUsersActionName'); }
  }
})
```

```css
span {font-family: monospace; font-weight: bold; color: red } h1,h2,h3 {font-size: medium; display: inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<span>This throws no error, and prints the whole details object.</span>
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{getUser.name}}</h1> |
  <h2>{{getUser.number}}</h2> |
  <h3>{{getUser.details}}</h3>
</div>
```

*Workaround*: with `.test` but with `v-if`:

```js
var globalUser = {
  name:"test",
  number:"9666-0503",
  details:{
    test:"cannot_access_this",
    second_field:"nope_no_go"
  }
};
var TYPES = {FETCH_USER: 'TYPESFETCHUSER'};
   
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {user: {}},
  mutations: {
    [TYPES.FETCH_USER](state, data) {
      state.user = data
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchUsersActionName({ commit }) {
      setTimeout(() => commit(TYPES.FETCH_USER, globalUser, 2000)); // simmulate asynchronous code
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getUser: state => state.user
  }
});
new Vue({
  store: store,
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapGetters(['getUser']),
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getData()
  },
  methods: {
    getData() { this.$store.dispatch('fetchUsersActionName'); }
  }
})
```

```css
span {font-family: monospace; font-weight: bold; color: red } h1,h2,h3 {font-size: medium; display: inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<span>This throws no error, because the v-if controls the displaying to only when .test is available.</span>
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{getUser.name}}</h1> |
  <h2>{{getUser.number}}</h2> |
  <h3 v-if="getUser.details">{{getUser.details.test}}</h3>
</div>
```

*Workaround*: with `.test` but with `user` initialized including a `details` property:

```js
var globalUser = {
  name:"test",
  number:"9666-0503",
  details:{
    test:"cannot_access_this",
    second_field:"nope_no_go"
  }
};
var TYPES = {FETCH_USER: 'TYPESFETCHUSER'};
   
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {user: {details: {}}},   // <============ THIS IS THE IMPORTANT, notice the  {details: {}}
  mutations: {
    [TYPES.FETCH_USER](state, data) {
      state.user = data
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchUsersActionName({ commit }) {
      setTimeout(() => commit(TYPES.FETCH_USER, globalUser, 2000)); // simmulate asynchronous code
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getUser: state => state.user
  }
});
new Vue({
  store: store,
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapGetters(['getUser']),
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getData()
  },
  methods: {
    getData() { this.$store.dispatch('fetchUsersActionName'); }
  }
})
```

```css
span {font-family: monospace; font-weight: bold; color: red } h1,h2,h3 {font-size: medium; display: inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<span>This throws no error, because the user initial value contains a "details" field already.</span>
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{getUser.name}}</h1> |
  <h2>{{getUser.number}}</h2> |
  <h3>{{getUser.details.test}}</h3>
</div>
```

**Why?**

This is because the code that updates `user` is asynchronous.

First time it tries to display `{{ getUser.name }}`, the `getUser.name` value is `undefined` so it *just shows nothing* (because Vue shows nothing when `{{ undefined }}`). Millisseconds later, `getUser.name` is updated and then begins to show the `name`. It's very fast, which is why you get the sensation that it never was `undefined`.

The same happens to `{{ getUser.number }}` and `{{ getUser.details }}`.

When it tries to display `{{ getUser.details.test }}`, on the other hand, it will throw an error because, at first, `getUser.details` is `undefined` so when  it tries to access `getUser.details.test` it is effectively the same as `undefined.test`, which is why it throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined`.

For workarounds, either use `v-if` or initialize `user` with a non-`undefined` `details` property (see last two demos above).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm don't follow,  the template stringifies objects to show them. Is that the issue?

Comment: No, its stringifying the whole object.  Displaying that.  But if I try to acecss those properties, it says undefined.   So  {{user.details.test}} is undefined.  But {{user.details}}  echoes out '{"test":"data","second_field":"more_data"}' as a string.  But I cant access the test or second_field as objects.  Theyre in that details string, as a string, instead of an object. Its only nested objects that this is happening on.  Returning objects with no nesting, I can access them perfectly fine

Comment: It is because the code is asynchronous. First time it tries to load, `getUser.name` is `undefined` so it *just shows nothing*. Millisseconds later, `getUser.name` is updated and then begins to thow the `name`. The same happens to `getUser.number` and `getUser.details`. OTOH, when you put `{{ getUser.details.test }}`, it will throw an error because, at first, `getUser.details` is `undefined` and `undefined.test` is an error.

Comment: yeah, but  why is it outputting a string?  Its not undefined.  Its a string

Comment: Have a look at the demos, specially the last, with `v-if`.

Comment: @KyleK it's outputting that string because accessing the `details` property of the initial value of `state.user` doesn't throw an error like accessing `state.user.details.test` does (which prevents further template updates). So when the `state.user` object updates after the async call, the template updates to display the new value of `state.user.details`, which is an object, and what you are seeing is how Vue renders an object as text.

Comment: @KyleK That's not a Vue vs jQuery thing. That's just a javascript thing. If you initialize `foo` to be `{}`, trying to access `foo.bar.baz` is going to error because `foo.bar` is `undefined`. That's what's happening in your case.

Comment: As a matter of fact, yes, you do have to worry when you are accessing deeply nested properties. In angular, for instance, you can use the elvis operator (`?.`), like `getUser?.details?.test`. But in Vue this is not yet supported because Evan doesn't want it ( https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4638 ) due to the elvis operator not being part of standard JS yet. If you ask me though, I bet it will be. It is currently at Stage 1 proposal ( https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining ), but some transpilers (like Babel) already support them. So it's just a matter of time.

Comment: Even with the checks there, it still doesnt work.  However....now it doesnt even render/.  Because obviously details always returns null.  So now it wont even just show the string.  It doesnt render.

Comment: Create a default user like `user: {details: {test: "I AM GROOT"}}` does it render? If it still doesn't. What's the error?? If no error, you must show us more code, there must be something else.

Comment: I already have a default user.  Doesnt work.  It renders a string.  First level is objects, nested levels are strings.   I think Ive given up though.  Just gonna stick with localStorage as my data store, and regular $.ajax calls in my methods.  It was working before when that was the case.